# I always get confused of using "used to" in a sentence

Tags: used-to

I've searched about it in Google and it says that I've got to use the word **used to** in a sentence everytime I talk about past habits or anything I used to do in the past.

But I am wondering why this sentence seems incorrect for me. And this is the sentence what I'm talking about

> I remember when I was young I would always think that i had super
>   powers because everytime **used to** expect it would definitely come true
>   and if i didnt **used to** expect it it wouldn't come true

I suppose theres something wrong about this sentence that I made. I think the word **used to** doesn't fit the sentence, I think I've got to remove the word **used to** from the sentence, and replace it with this one

> because every time I expect it I would come and when I don't expect it
>   it wouldn't come true

Answer (score 1):

As you surmise, the sentence is a bit of a mouthful, as though spoken by a child.

And **used to** meaning that an action or practice was habitual, does not sit happily in the midst of it.

The sentence, with my insertions in brackets, might have been better constructed as:

> I remember (that) when I was young I would always think that I had super powers because every time I expected (that something) would definitely come true (it did) and if I didn't expect it, it wouldn't come true.

Your suggested construction, set out below, doesn't work because of some minor mistakes and the verb tense:

> "because every time I expect it I would come and when I don't expect it it wouldn't come true".

It needs to be changed slightly to situate the memory in the past:

> because every time I expect**ed** it, **it** would come **true** and when I **didn't** expect it, it wouldn't come true.

Comment: Hello thanks to you. Sorry because I just started to learn English. I am 14 years old :)

Comment: @maxcabs Well you're doing a lot better than many people twice your age. Keep it up.

Comment: I've still got aa question. How to use the word "would have" in a sentence. It also confuse me.

Comment: @maxcabs Ask your question on Stackexchange, making it clear what puzzles you!